# When using Jupyter, I have to install python modules with Conda and not cmd prompt. Why?

Tags: python, cmd, module, jupyter-notebook, conda

I'm pretty new to programming so forgive my ignorance.

When installing certain python packages/modules in the cmd prompt I am able to import them fine when using Jupyter Notebook. But some modules Jupyter Notebook cannot import without installing via Conda first. Why is this?

Comment: It's just preferable to install deps via Conda, you can install them via the command line too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to system and environment that you are using and not the programming :)

Since you are a beginner, let us understand the concepts first rather than solving the problem.

**Python** code is run on an interpreter that is installed on your machine.

**Jupyter** is a web application that takes code using a given language's interpreter. So Jupyter, on its own doesn't run your code. It uses the interpreter installed on a system(your local machine).

**Conda** is a package manager and also an environment manager. That means using conda, you can create a virtual environment on your machine and that virtual environment can have its own installation of an interpreter. This virtual environment can have its own copy of the packages/modules as well.

Now comes the best part: The jupyter notebook can be asked to use any of the interpreters including the ones installed on a virtual environment.

So most likely, you are running the jupyter notebook from an environment which doesn't have the required dependencies. So either run the jupyter notebook outside the environment or install the required packages in the environment where your jupyter notebook is running.

To know which environment is being used by your jupyter notebook, run below lines from the jupyter notebook cell:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

If you **don't get** something like `/usr/bin/python` then the jupyter is running inside an environment. So you have to install all the packages/modules inside that environment only.

Comment: Excellent, I think I understand. When I start Jupyter using the shortcut on my taskbar it opens Jupyter in a V Env created via Conda and I therefore have to install modules to that in order to import them. I start Jupyter from within the cmd prompt it starts outside of any environments and therefore my base modules work. Many thanks!

Comment: Exactly! Please do accept the answer if it helped you :)